# I only got a lot of cons folder inside \data\data, and I can't found my app name folder. Anyone have the solution for this?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: My Image]

Actually in my application i instantiated an object of local sq-lite, and i can't see the database in the android monitor file explorer it just displaying can allowance displaying package names.

Comment: Make the Name collumn wider.